# High dimensional vector space references

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, vector-spaces, book-recommendation

Is there any good text book or review papers that introduce high dimensional vector spaces and its peculiarities as compared to generic/low-dimensional vector spaces?

For example, high dimensional unit sphere $S^n$ ($n \gg 4$) has most of its mass near the boundary in an $n-1$ dimensional annulus.   A treatise generically introducing linear algebra or vector spaces will not develop you intuition regarding the peculiarities of high-dimensional vector spaces, and will generally not spend a lot of ink on explicitly discussing the properties of them, since it is "generic".

Comment: What do you mean by "high dimensional"? The beauty of linear algebra and matrix theory for finite dimensional spaces is to study them regardless of their dimension (in opposition to high school geometry that differentiate between planes and spaces) and the usual distinction is between finite and infinite dimension.

Comment: If by "high dimensional" you mean "infinite dimensional," then you should be looking into texts about "functional analysis".

Comment: @Problemaniac as the comments on your question suggest, we're have a hard time deciphering what exactly it is that you're after.  I suggest you edit your question to clarify what you mean by "high-dimensional" or "peculiarities".  Even better: you could tell us what it is that has motivated you to look into this in the first place to give us a better idea of what you're trying to understand.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think the edit helps to understand the question. Can you clarify the sentence "For example, high dimensional unit sphere Sn (n≫4) has most of its mass near the boundary in an n−1 dimensional annulus." and its relation to linear algebra? 
As for your second sentence in the edit, if a treatise on linear algebra does not emphasize peculiarities of high-dimension, it is probably because there is no peculiarity. Or you should explain which kind of peculiarity you have in mind.

Comment: I think the problem people are having with your question stems from the fact that the kind of peculiarity you're talking about isn't really a matter of linear algebra (vector spaces) -- it's a matter of geometry (Euclidean spaces). After all, a sphere is not a linear object!

Comment: @Micah, the proposition about $S^n$ spheres is actually true only if the embedding vector space has an Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Taladris, it is obvious that the proposition about $S^n$ is only true for $n \gg 4$ and is false for low dimensions such as $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$.  A regular linear algebra or vector space introduction will not develop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you might be interested in Keith Ball's nice article ''An elementary introduction to modern convex geometry" and its references. It discusses many issues relevant to the geometric behavior you mention. It's available at http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~Vybiral/GHS/ball.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by "higher dimensional" you mean spaces with dimensions higher than 2 or 3 or 4, as used commonly in physics, engineering, computer graphics, and high-school calculus and geometry.

If so, then look for books about "linear algebra". This is the study of vector spaces with arbitrary dimension (say $n$), including infinite dimensions. Most of the theory does not make any special mention of the special cases $n=2,3, \text{or }4$. A reasonable place to start is [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra).

But, as you start to study more abstract vector spaces, don't forget what you know about the three-dimensional space in which we all live. 3D geometry and 3D vectors represented by "arrows" provide a valuable guide to intuition, even though many mathematicians would not view this as "real" linear algebra.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought the questioner's problem was,bubba-they'd learned linear algebra incorrectly i.e. in low dimensional Euclidean spaces using "arrow" vectors. This material is important,but let's face it-it's not really linear algebra in the modern sense,is it?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 -- I don't agree that using 3D geometry is necessarily an "incorrect" approach to linear algebra. In fact, in my view, linear algebra without mention of 3D geometry is boring and mysterious. I learned linear algebra the abstract mathematician's way, mostly as a process of manipulating symbols with indices, with no pictures. Many years later I found out that all that stuff has some physical meaning and some value in real-world problems.

Comment: I'm all for concrete examples and applications,but they need to presented in conjunction with the rigorous theory. Otherwise,the student gets the idea that that's all there is to the subject. They have to be presented in proper context and it shouldn't be an either/or choice.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to clarify your question because it doesn't make any sense as stated.  I completely agree with Taladris-this is the kind of question that betrays the fact the student doesn't really understand the subject of thier question as well as they think.The theory of finite dimensional vector spaces i.e. basic linear algebra is completely general regardless of dimension as long as the dimension is finite.  Another answerer wondered whether or not you meant infinite dimensional versus finite dimensional spaces.  That was also my initial thought-but looking at the question again,I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about. It sounds more like you studied matrix algebra and "arrow" vectors in low dimensions.If so, you need to relearn linear algebra correctly now-that is,on abstract vector spaces using a good linear algebra book, such as Curtis. If you **did** mean infinite dimensional vector spaces,then you'll need to learn a considerable amount of hard analysis before you can tackle that mountain,from what it looks like to me.As long as the dimension is finite, the number of vectors in any basis for the vector space is unique.When you move into infinite dimensional spaces, that's no longer true. But this isn't even the most serious problem with infinite dimensional vector spaces. We can prove using the axiom of choice-or one of it's variants-that every vector space has a basis. The problem is that when dealing with infinite dimensional vector spaces, there's no clear way to construct a basis. Think about it-what does it mean to represent an element of a vector space as an **infinite** linear combination of linearly independent vectors? In some infinite dimensional spaces, such as those that occur in Fourier analysis, this idea can be made precise by convergent infinite series-but this is really an unusual case. In most cases, we can't even state exactly what this means, let alone come up with a procedure for constructing one. This is really what makes functional analysis and operator theory a completely different-and fascinating!-ball game then plain old linear algebra-you have to use other kinds of subsets of the vector space to specify the dimension. But to tackle it,you'll need **at least** a strong background in undergraduate real analysis on metric spaces in addition to a good understanding of abstract linear algebra.

Hope that helped clarify your question. I hope.

**UPDATE** Alright,your edited question makes much more sense now. But your question really isn't about vector spaces per se, it's about higher dimensional geometry-i.e. the topology and geometry of n-dimensional manifolds. In which case,what you really want is a recommendation for a book on modern differential geometry and topology, of which there are legion. The problem is I doubt from your question that you have the proper background yet to study this amazing topic. To even begin to study this topic,you need a good background in both basic topology and undergraduate real analysis,in addition to a strong understanding of linear algebra. Indeed, the questions you're asking actually require considerably more to even begin to answer,including a graduate course in algebraic topology. A good beginner's place to start is John McCleary's *Geometry From A Differentiable Viewpoint*, which not only presents the basic concepts of low dimensional differential geometry, but does so from a historical viewpoint the beginner will find very enlightening. It also contains many good recommendations for further study. That being said-you clearly have a lot to learn before you can begin to seriously study these topics,so I'd get started on that if I were you!